# Change format of date in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepicker

Following the Android SDK tutorials I have implemented my first basic date picker dialog. It works fine but is there any way to change the format of the date shown?

Example:
The date picker dialog displays the date as "17 Oct 2010". I would it like to be displayed as "17 10 2010".

Greetings,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to extend the DatePicker class with your own, and modify it as you like. Afaik there are no attributes that you could use to easily modify this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I've been guessing ;-)